# NSDictionary to display each item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 1; i<=count; i++) {

    NSString *j = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",i ];

    NSArray *fields = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       @"name",nil];
    //@"title",@"mobile",@"email",@"website"
    [requestExecute setMethod:@"execute" withObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                          @"testdb",userid,@"admin",@"res.partner.contact",@"read",j,fields,nil]];
    NSDictionary *records=[self executeXMLRPCRequest:requestExecute];

NSLog(@"\nKey : %@ value : \n",records);
```

The output looks like

```
2011-04-09 12:34:32.431 Erp[1571:207]
 (  
        {  
        email = "benoit@yahoo.com";  
        id = 1;  
        mobile = 12345;  
        name = Mortier;  
        title = "Ms.";  
        website = "www.benoit.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.515 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "laurent@hotmail.com";  
        id = 2;  
        mobile = 23455;  
        name = Jacot;  
        title = "M.";  
        website = "www.laurent.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.599 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "thomas@yahoo.com";  
        id = 3;  
        mobile = 34567;  
        name = Passot;  
        title = "M.";  
        website = "www.thomas.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.683 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "etienne@yahoo.com";  
        id = 4;  
        mobile = 45678;  
        name = Lacarte;  
        title = Mss;  
        website = "www.etienne.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.767 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "chow@gmail.com";  
        id = 5;  
        mobile = 56789;  
        name = Tang;  
        title = Mss;  
        website = "www.chow.com";  
    }  
)  
2011-04-09 12:34:32.851 Erp[1571:207] (  
        {  
        email = "hudson@gmail.com";  
        id = 6;  
        mobile = 1237091;  
        name = Wong;  
        title = "M.";  
        website = "www.hudson.com";  
    }  
)
```

This prints each record one by one. Now I'd like to get each field in this record one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what requestExecute does, but if you want to loop through all the values in the NSDictionary you can use [records allKeys] which will return an NSArray of all the keys in the dictionary.

Comment: The requestExecute is to perform an XMLPassing . the function which collects the data from the open erp system.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C 2.0 supports a pretty handy fast enumeration syntax collections...

```
for(NSString *aKey in records){
    NSLog(@"%@", [[records valueForKey:aKey] description]);
}
```

Comment: [__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b4e8f0
2011-04-09 11:11:08.221 Erp[985:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b4e8f0' 

while doing the action you had specified i received such an error.

Comment: I've updated the code extract, I missed the string for at in the log statement :)